# How to get Announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges

How to share a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses.

I want this to earn the announcer badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the "share" button below a question or an answer:

[image]

This will bring up the standard share buttons for Google Plus, Facebook and Twitter, which will place a link to the post on your Plus page / timeline / feed. You will also be able to copy a link to the question that identifies you as the person who shared it; these [look like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114621/184688):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/<question-id>/<user-id>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/<answer-id>/<user-id>
```

where `<user-id>` is your user ID. (You can get this by going to your profile and looking at the search bar on the top right.)

You will get the Announcer badge, for example, if 25 unique IP addresses click on any of such links. Be aware, though, that there are mechanisms in place to detect [sock puppeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) so if you try to access it yourself from 25 different computers the system may detect that and discount those visits. Also, as EnergyNumbers points out, [links shared within the SE network do not count towards referral badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114608/184688).

Answer (score 2):

You can find the full badge description [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

You need to use the "share" link and share the question with others (Sharing it on an SE site will *not* work). This is usually done via Twitter/Facebook/etc. If enough people click on it, you get a badge.

Comment: Does it really not work if you post a "share" link on SE? That's very interesting, I didn't know that. Is there a post on the mother meta where it's mentioned?

Comment: Heh, just found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114608/164022